# What is this type of math notation called? (+ 4 5)

Tags: notation, arithmetic

So I've been looking for a general name of this type of mathematics notation (google hasn't been very useful) so that I can learn more about it. Basically, the symbols are in the form of functions and the numbers are the inputs to the function.  + is the function taking 4 and 5, outputting 9 so, (+4 5) = 9. Formulaic  (* a b ) = a * b.  Where ' * ' can be any basic math symbol.  More complicated forms are: (+ 4 (+ 5 1)) = 4 + (5+1) = 10. 4 being input for 'a' and (5+1) being 'b' in (* a b ).

Hope it makes sense.

Comment: AFAIK this is looks like the LISP programming language.

Comment: Yes, lisp and other computer languages use this, and I just want to know the name for this type of math, so I'm not sure whats with all these down votes, seems childish

Comment: Looks like arithmetics in  [Polish Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation), except the Polish Notation does not need - and does not use - parentheses.

Comment: @CiaPan As Ahmed Hussein has said, it is typical of the use of LISP language which uses a kind of "polish notation" but it is just the tip of the iceberg. This language is well described by saying that it implements the logic of **$\lambda$ calculus** (www.inf.fu-berlin.de/lehre/WS03/alpi/lambda.pdf) defined by logician Church.

Comment: @JeanMarie I know what Lisp is (some time ago I knew some dialect of Lisp), but the question was 'for a general name of this *type of mathematics*', not about the name of *a programming language* which uses this type of maths.

Comment: It's not a "type of mathematics". It's just a trivial variation on notation. Good notations are important in mathematics, but a different notation does not make a different mathematics.

Comment: There is typically no need for parentheses around this kind of expressions, because they are not ambiguous.

Comment: Just as one more data point for you, within LISP and related languages, these are referred to as [S-expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-expression).

Comment: Lisp uses parentheses because (among other reasons) + and * are actually sum and product functions on an arbitrary number of operands, rather than binary operators.

Comment: @Random832: IOW, for what we conventionally write as Σ and Π.

Comment: @Édouard They're not ambgious if you define each one as a binary operator, but if you want them to be n-ary, so that you can do `(+ 2 3 4)` instead of `(+ (+ 2 3) 4)` (or `(+ 2 (+ 3 4))`), then you'd need them.  For associative operators, that's nice.  But you're right, if all the operators are fixed-arity, then no grouping is necessary.

Answer (score 42):

It is normal [Polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation) or prefix notation.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was very helpful to me

Comment: And because nobody noted it yet, `4 5 + 6 7 * -` (like [Forth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forth_(programming_language))) is known as Postfix notation or Reverse Polish Notation.

Comment: @cat and the only proper way to use a calculator

Comment: @casey I agree! I find Forth and [Factor](http://factorcode.org) *much* easier than remembering all this order-of-operations junk, and so they're what I use as a desktop calculator :) I never got the chance to own one of those RPN HP calculators, unfortunately

Comment: @cat If you use iOS or a Mac, PCalc is pretty cheap and works extremely well. It even has HP-esque programming (think keystroke, but nicer).

Comment: Cool, I knew what RPN was but never knew what the non-reverse version was!

Comment: Worth noting that reverse polish notation removes the need to use parentheses to determine operation order and most certainly easier to parse by a programmer than the more traditional `(4+5) - (6*7)`

Comment: @cat: You'd probably enjoy writing in the PostScript language, since it also uses RPN. However, it doesn't have operators like `+` and `*`, instead it has functions `add` and `mul`.